Can I undo a Vote to Leave Open
I have just voted to leave a question open. Then I have read it again and I have realised that no, I think it is off-topic, so I searched here for a button to undo my previous vote;  I also checked in the Help Center for an undo action. As I could not find one, I just voted to close the question.
Apparently, the consequence of my double action seems to be that there is one more user that would close the question AND one more user that would leave it open. Is it so and, if so, does it makes sense? Shouldn't I be able to undo my previous vote and then vote to close?

Now when I think of it, it doesn't really make a lot of sense, but apparently, one can't change any of one's reviews. If you approve an edit or cast a close/open vote, you can't go back and undo it. Eventually, it means that if you review something and then change your mind, you'd have to rely on other users' opinion about the same post.

You can undo a close vote, but not a reopen vote. So what you've done is exactly what you described - raised the reopen votes count by 1, and raised the close votes count by 1.
The request to be able to retract close votes was initially declined (way back in 2009):

declining -- you can always cast a reopen vote if the post gets closed.
Also note that all close votes automatically expire after two days.
(and for that matter reopen votes, or any other vote that attempts to reach a threshold -- otherwise, over an absurdly long period of time, say 10 years, everything would reach the threshold eventually through a tiny trickle of accumulated votes)

Emphasis mine. This is a minor vote hiccup, but if nothing happens to the post your votes will expire in a few days anyway.

Thanks both of you for the explanation.
